# How to pass a callback to EM_ASM for c++?

Tags: c++, emscripten

I do not know how to pass the value asynchronously to EM_ASM, here's how I try to do it (but JS says it's not a function):

```
const auto testFunc = [] (const char* data)
{
    printf("data: %s\n", data);
}
EM_ASM_(
{
    var funcResult = ($0);
    var text = "data";
    var lengthBytes = lengthBytesUTF8(text) + 1;
    var stringOnWasmHeap = _malloc(lengthBytes);
    stringToUTF8(text, stringOnWasmHeap, lengthBytes);
    // exception thrown: TypeError: funcResult is not a function
    funcResult(stringOnWasmHeap);
}, testFunc);
```

The documentation says that you can use a function (em_str_callback_func) of the em_str_callback_func type. But it doesn't say how to use it.
https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802693/call-c-function-from-javascript-asynchronously-using-emscripten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about passing callbacks, but if what you want to do is to return a value from JS, then the [docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native) have such an example: you have to use `EM_ASM_INT` instead:

```
int x = EM_ASM_INT({
  console.log('I received: ' + $0);
  return $0 + 1;
}, 100);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

The [API reference](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.EM_ASM_INT) has another example for returning a string:

```
char *str = (char*)EM_ASM_INT({
  var jsString = 'Hello with some exotic Unicode characters: Tässä on yksi lumiukko: ☃, ole hyvä.';
  var lengthBytes = lengthBytesUTF8(jsString)+1;
  // 'jsString.length' would return the length of the string as UTF-16
  // units, but Emscripten C strings operate as UTF-8.
  var stringOnWasmHeap = _malloc(lengthBytes);
  stringToUTF8(jsString, stringOnWasmHeap, lengthBytes);
  return stringOnWasmHeap;
});
printf("UTF8 string says: %s\n", str);
free(str); // Each call to _malloc() must be paired with free(), or heap memory will leak!
```

Once you have the value in C you can just call your `testfunc` directly.

Comment: the problem is that I need to return the value asynchronously

Comment: You mean that you'll call out to JS code, but it won't be able to return a value immediately? In that case you'll probably need to use [Asyncify](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/asyncify.html#returning-values).